# Передача данных между станицами node js

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, хранение-данных, node-modules

Я начинающий программист на node.js и пытаюсь заставить сайт передавать логин пользователя (в принципе, можно заменить на генерируемый ключ сессии, но не суть) между станицами. Код не слишком доработанный и опрятный, но суть проблемы объясняет:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
let app = express();

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    let login = req.body.login;
    let password = req.body.password;

    //Проверка данных введённых пользователем

    if (isOk == true)
    {
        res.end(`<script>document.location.replace("/getData")</script>`);
    }
})

app.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
    login = "А вот тут мне нужен логин введённый пользователем";
    res.end(fs.readdirSync(`./data/${login}`));
})
```

Пробовал сделать через куки, но понимаю, что так не правильно:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let app = express();
app.use(cookieParser("secret_key"));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    let login = req.body.login;
    let password = req.body.password;

    //Проверка данных введённых пользователем

    if (isOk == true)
    {
        res.cookies('login', login);
        res.end(`<script>document.location.replace("/getData")</script>`);
    }
})

app.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
    login = req.cookies("login")';
    res.end(fs.readdirSync(`./data/${login}`));
})
```

Так как некоторые браузеры их блокируют.

Как в итоге лучше передавать данные между страницами?
Через пост запрос не вариант, на сайте я использую ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В web-разработке под сессией понимается промежуток времени, в течении которого пользователь находится на сайте. Сессия начинается в момент захода на сайт и заканчивается при закрытии вкладки браузера или при переходе в пределах текущей вкладки на другой ресурс, и позволяет сохранять, например, данные в действиях пользователя, которые не теряются при переходе на другую страницу.

> Данные хранятся на сервере, а идентификатор сессии на стороне клиента
> в файле cookie. Причем express-session по умолчанию использует
> cookie-parser для разбора файлов cookie.

Для использования в Node.js сессии необходимо установить npm модуль express-session.

```
npm install express-session --save
```

Инициализация Node.js сессии осуществляется с помощью функции промежуточной обработки.

```
app.js

const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  session = require('express-session')

const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = 7000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'you secret key',
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
)

app.post('/ad', (req, res) => {
  req.session.showAd = req.body.showAd
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.showAd)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log(`Server listens http://${host}:${port}`)
})
```

> Модуль body-parser необходим для корректной обработки передаваемых в
> теле данных.

Пример опирается на то, что пользователь может указать, показывать ему на сайте рекламу или нет. При выборе отправляется POST-запрос, который записывает в сессию результат, который потом доступен во всех маршрутах приложения.

Во время инициализации Node.js сессии с помощью объекта можно задать следующие опции:

- cookie - настройка cookie хранения идентификатора сессии, передается объект с опциями (подробно здесь);
- genid - функция, которая возвращает новый идентификатор сессии в виде строки (по умолчанию используется функция, генерирующая идентификаторы на основе библиотеки uid-safe);
- resave - булевое значение, указывает, нужно ли пересохранять сессию в хранилище, если она не изменилась (по умолчанию false);
- rolling - булевое значение, указывающее, нужно ли устанавливать идентификатор сессии cookie на каждый запрос (по умолчанию false);
- saveUninitialized - булевое значение, если true, то в хранилище будут попадать пустые сессии;
- secret - строка, которой подписывается сохраняемый в cookie идентификатор сессии;
- store - экземпляр хранилища, которое будет использоваться для хранения сессии (рассмотрено ниже в этой статье).

> Node.js сессия считается пустой, если в конце обработки запроса в нее
> не было записано никаких данных.

В работе с сессией в таком формате, как приведено в примере, есть один важный нюанс - конструкция будет работать только для одного пользователя. Объект Node.js сессии глобальный и будет перезаписываться данными последнего пользователя. Чтобы избежать этого используются хранилища оперативной памяти.

Самыми распространенными хранилищами являются MemCached и Redis. Здесь рассмотрим пример хранения Node.js сессии с использованием Redis. Но сначала нужно установить два npm модуля.

```
npm install redis connect-redis --save
```

Теперь пример.

```
app.js

const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  session = require('express-session'),
  redisStorage = require('connect-redis')(session),
  redis = require('redis'),
  client = redis.createClient()

const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = 7000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(
  session({
    store: new redisStorage({
      host: host,
      port: 6379,
      client: client
    }),
    secret: 'you secret key',
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
)

app.post('/ad', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.key) req.session.key = req.sessionID

  req.session.key[req.sessionID].showAd = req.body.showAd
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.key[req.sessionID].showAd)
  res.sendStatus(200)
})

app.listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log(`Server listens http://${host}:${port}`)
})
```

Для записи данных пользователя в Redis свойству key сессии присваивается объект с ее уникальным идентификатором в виде ключа и объектом данных в качестве значения.

По умолчанию время жизни Node.js сессии в Redis равно времени жизни ее идентификатора в cookie (задается параметром maxAge).

Для переопределения времени жизни в хранилище используйте параметр ttl, указываемый в миллисекундах у экземпляра хранилища.

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: new redisStorage({
      ttl: 3600000
    })
  })
)
```

оригинал [тут](https://xsltdev.ru/nodejs/tutorial/sessions/)